# Cannot set NODE_ENV to production on Express 4

Tags: node.js, express

I'm facing an issue when trying to set `NODE_ENV=production` in various ways. The app never goes into production mode and would require assistance.

I have tried by setting in my .zshrc as this is the shell I use with `export NODE_ENV=production` and also by editing the `/etc/environment` file on my Debian and Fedora systems but with no luck.

I have obviously sourced both the files before launching or restarting the app.

To test if the setting is effective I tried to log to console the following:

```
process.env.NODE_ENV
app.env
```

but it always returns development.

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Why dont you set the env while starting the app server? Something like, `NODE_ENV=production node app.js`

Comment: I start the app with pm2 and I have also tried the env settings from the pm2 docs but cannot understand how to implement.

Comment: pm2 will still use a script in your package.json to start the app. More details can be found here http://pm2.keymetrics.io/docs/usage/environment/